# Multiline listing within multicolumn row

Tags: tables, listings, line-breaking, multicolumn

I have a problem putting a listing (using `lstlisting` package) within a table. The problem is that I want to put a *multiline* listing in a row taking 2 columns.

The following minimal example shows what I want to achieve. However, `multicolumn` wraps the listing on a single line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{
  \begin{lstlisting}^^J
    1st line
    2nd line
  ^^J\end{lstlisting}
} \\ \hline
some text & some text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to wrap the listing in a `vbox` or `minipage`, but that didn't help.

Any alternatives to `multicolumn`, or other ways to get a multiline listing in a table like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an `l` column is like `\mbox` and is for single line material normally you would just need to change `l` to `p{5cm}` in your `\multicolumn`, however listings like most verbatim things can not be in the argument of another command so a sleight of hand is needed to avoid putting it in the argument of `\multicolumn`.

I also change `begin{center}` to `\centering` to avoid extra white space, and changed `[h]` as `[h]` means "please take all floats to end of document, which isn't normally the desired behaviour.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|}{}
  \begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    1st line
    2nd line
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}\hfill\vline\kern-\arrayrulewidth
 \\ \hline
some text & some text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've made my day, this indeed solves my problem!

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,array,varwidth}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| } \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|}{}
  \varwidth{\linewidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    1st line
    2nd line
  \end{lstlisting}
  \endvarwidth\hfill\vline
 \\ \hline
some text & some text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 yes I wondered about varwidth but thought I'd keep it simple,